# Invalid number of breaks?

Tags: r, syntax

I'm trying to make a confidence interval for practice and I keep getting an error referring to:

> an 'invalid number of breaks' at hist.default(boot.dist).

I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere here.

Any advice or help would be very much appreciated at this point.

```
b=1000
boot.dist = rep(0,b)
for (i in 1:b) {
boot.sample = sample(ACS$Income, replace = TRUE)
boot.dist[i] = mean(boot.sample)
}
hist(boot.dist)
```

Comment: Welcome! It really helps if your questions are both [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which this is) and [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (this is not). Please read those two links and then edit your question. (For instance, because we don't know what `ACS` is, we cannot reproduce your problem.)

Comment: ... this error will come up, though, if you have no finite non-`NA` data in `ACS$Income`. Check to insure `any(! (is.na(ACS$Income) | is.infinite(ACS$Income)) )`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `ACS$Income` is array of NA.

Example, this code will reproduce error exactly like yours:

```
boot.dist[1:1000]<-NA 
hist(boot.dist )
```

Error in hist.default(boot.dist) : invalid number of 'breaks'